# Graph planarity testing using Wagner's Theorem

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Wagner's theorem states that a graph is planar if and only if it does not contain a minor that is isomorphic to $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$. An undirected graph H is called a minor of the graph $G$ if $H$ can be formed from $G$ by deleting edges and vertices and by contracting edges.

On the other hand, [here](http://cglab.ca/~morin/teaching/4804/notes/planarity.pdf) and [here](http://cs.rkmvu.ac.in/~sghosh/public_html/nitp_igga/slides/shreesh-planarity-patna.pdf) it's said that the algorithm of planarity testing (non-polynomial, of course) could look like:

> 1) Choose an edge of G
>
> 2) Shrink it
>
> 3) If $6$ vertices are remaining - check for $K_{3,3}$, if $5$ - check for $K_{5}$
>
> 4) Repeat for all combinations

**Question:** Is the aforementioned algorithm valid? It seems that the algorithm performs only the contractions. However, minors could also be formed by deleting edges and vertices.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm works as long as you start with a connected graph.

It may be easier to see this from Kuratowski's Theorem which characterizes non-planar graphs as graphs that have a subdivision of $K_5$ or $K_{3,3}$ as a subgraph.

Say your graph has a subdivision of $K_5$ with vertices $v_1,\dots,v_5$ being the five main vertices of the subdivision. Contract all the edges of $G$ except any edge $v_iv_j$ for $1\leq i< j\leq 5$. This will give you a $K_5$. The case where your graph contains a $K_{3,3}$ follows identically.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Could you please clarify the 3rd step in the algorithm. It's clearly not checking for isomorphism. Is it about K33 and K5 being subgraphs?

Comment: @Konstantin Step three you would want to check for isomorphism. Normally this is hard to do, but you are only doing it on six vertices.(When you are on 5 vertices, you don't need to check for isomorphism because of the symmetry of $K_5$. It is also looking for a subgraph(at least for the $K_{3,3}$ case.